# Traversing SQLAlchemy relationships - TypeError and problems with backref

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

After trying to create a post in my flask application, this error message shows up `TypeError: 'author' is an invalid keyword argument for Post`.

Here is the following code in my models.py:

```py
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)
    colleges_accepted = db.relationship('CollegesAccepted', backref='author', lazy=True)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', primaryjoin="User.id==Post.author_id")
    ...

class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    ...

class CollegesAccepted(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    ...
```

Here is the code for routes.py:

```py
@app.route("/post/new", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def new_post():
    form = PostForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        post = Post(title=form.title.data,
                    content=form.content.data,
                    author=current_user,
                    college_attending=current_user.college_attending)
        db.session.add(post)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your post has been created!', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('create_post.html', title='New Post', form=form)
```

But this doesn't give me the intended result - when displaying the post, I want to display attributes from the author/User as well as the post content. I want to use the relationships that I defined in models.py to be able to do something like this in the html/jinja2 template:

```
{% for college in post.author.colleges_accepted_to %}
    {{ college }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Maybe just this: in routes.py you add `Post(author=current_user)` but the Post object in models.py only has `author_id` ?

Comment: Then this error shows up: "sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: <unprintable InterfaceError object>" @ChristianMacht

Comment: Have you tried `author_id=current_user.id` ? Your class requires an `int` there. `current_user` is (I guess) an object and `current_user.username` is a string. RE your last comment, you can retrieve information about the User via the User.id associated with the post.

Comment: current_user.id and current_user.username both works; however, I want to loop through all the posts and post each post. By using those two methods (assigning .id or .username to author_id) I am not saving the object to it. Thus i will not be able to post the colleges accepted in the post @ChristianMacht

Comment: @ChristianMacht I edited in the question what I want the end result to be on the html page

Comment: What about the fact that you call it `colleges_accepted_to` in your template, but `colleges_accepted` in your models.py file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set a backref on the `colleges_accepted` relationship, but not on the `posts` relationship. So your `post` object has no idea how to get its `author`.

Also, you declare `colleges_accepted` but then use `colleges_accepted_to` in your template.